# Visual Studio 2008 MFC drag dialog without title and detect all mouse events

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm asked to add new feature to an existing program. The program consists of a dialog without title/border. I need couple of things:

1. When the user simply clicks inside the dialog area, just close it;
2. Move the dialog when the user mouse-down inside its area and drag

Here's what I found so far:

```
void MyDialog::onMessageReceived(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        lastX=LOWORD(lParam);
        lastY=HIWORD(lParam);
        SendMessage(DlgHandle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        if (LOWORD(lParam)==lastX && HIWORD(lParam)==lastY)
            onKillButtonClick();
        break;
}}
```

EDIT:
This function is called in this way:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK MyDialog::dialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    _this->onMessageReceived(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Moving the window works very well, but looks like the WM_LBUTTONUP event is lost. I had to click twice to get it fired.
Hope someone can help me...

EDIT:
Using Spy++ I saw that WM_LBTTONUP is fired, but immediately after a new WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN is emitted.

Comment: I think your approach for moving the dialog is not entirely correct, you should rather look into using [`OnNcHitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923b34d9.aspx). I suppose the WM_LBUTTONUP is eaten by your WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN hack.

Comment: BTW the interaction you describe is rather puzzling for the user. If I have understood correctly, the dialog is closed when the user clicks on it and then releases the button without moving the mouse, but when he clicks and moves the mouse _before_ releasing the button, the window moves.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Michael, that's exactly the behaviour  I need. Do you know if there is any way to avoid the WM_LBUTTONUP being "eaten" by the other message?

Comment: I was able to reproduce more or less the behaviour your describe, and I don't have an explanation. But are you sure this interaction is good? It seems rather confusing to me : click with moving moves the dialog, click without moving closes the dialog.

Comment: This dialog means there is a remote connection open on the computer. It simply display a close icon. The user may want to close the connection by clicking this small dialog, but he may also want to move it if it is covering some interesting part on the screen

Comment: There is one other possibility that comes into my mind: that is not using the  WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN hack but tracking dialog yourself, by responding to WM_MOUSEMOVE and moving the dialog until the button has been released. 15 lines of code or so should do the job.

Comment: BTW the `OnNcHitTest` method mentioned in my first comment doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree with Michael Walz - this is a very confusing behavior: the processing of the mouse up event depends on whether or not it has moved... What if it moved just a little bit? I would much rather dismiss this dialog with a different action - click on the icon, right-click, etc.

However, the correct way to let the user move your captionless window is to process `WM_NCHITTEST` message and return `HTCAPTION`:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
    SetWindowLong(hDlg, DWL_MSGRESULT, HTCAPTION);
    return HTCAPTION;
```

Unfortunately, Windows then will take over all mouse events, so, as you observed, you would never get `WM_LBUTTONUP`. You have an option to set a short timer and see if the user started to move your window; cancel it when you get `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` message. If that timer fires - close your window. Yes, it's also awkward, but no more thatn your proposal.

Another way is to handle the move yourself:

```
static bool bDragging(false), bMoved(false);
static POINT pt1 = {}, pt2 = {};
static RECT r;
switch (message)
{
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    GetWindowRect(hDlg, &r);
    pt1 = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
    ClientToScreen(hDlg, &pt1);
    bDragging = true;
    bMoved = false;
    break;
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    if (bDragging)
    {
        pt2 = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        ClientToScreen(hDlg, &pt2);
        if (pt2.x != pt1.x || pt2.y != pt1.y)
        {
            OffsetRect(&r, pt2.x - pt1.x, pt2.y - pt1.y);
            SetWindowPos(hDlg, 0, r.left, r.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
            pt1 = pt2;
            bMoved = true;
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    bDragging = false;
    if (!bMoved)
        PostMessage(hDlg, WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL, 0);
    bMoved = false;
    break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
```